# NFSGanesha Caches kerberos uid/gid for the client

Tags: kerberos, nfs, nfsclient, mit-kerberos

I mounted an export in NFS client , i have provided the "750" user permission for the export.

I started with the user who has RW access. for example "user1".

How to disable to caching at the NFSGanesha side?
Is it caching for the clients IP at the NFSGanesha?

This looks like security issue when multiple users trying to use the 
same NFS Client machines!

Could you throw some lights on this?

- kinit user1 (RW access user)
- I am able to write some files kinit
  user2 (Only Read Access)
- Still i am able to write some files (but
  uid/gid is coming for the files as user1) Verified the log, it is
  confirming it proceed the authorisation with previous user.

NFSGanesha Log:

[image]

If I restart NFS Ganesha service (server side), it works as expected (client side when i try to write file. I got permission denied)